# JQuery/JavaScript change in the checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have a simple `div` with multiple checkboxes in it. I want to look for any change in the checkbox to make an ajax query.
This code is not able to see the changes in those checkboxes. What is the right way to do it?

```js
$(document).on('change', '#listfilters checkbox', function(e) {
        if(this.checked) {
            alert("changed");
          // checkbox is checked
        }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="listfilters">
    <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="showall" name="showall" value=0>&nbsp;
    <label for="showall">Show All</label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="showfl" name="showfl" value=0>&nbsp;
    <label for="showfl">Filtered</label>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: change your selector to `$(document).on('change', '#listfilters input[type=checkbox]', function(e) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to qualify the checkbox part of the selector. Change it to `#listfilters [type=checkbox]`

```js
$(document).on('change', '#listfilters [type=checkbox]', function(e) {
        if(this.checked) {
            alert("changed");
          // checkbox is checked
        }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="listfilters">
    <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="showall" name="showall" value=0>&nbsp;
    <label for="showall">Show All</label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="showfl" name="showfl" value=0>&nbsp;
    <label for="showfl">Filtered</label>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `document`, you can select directly your `div` for a quick/faster selector.

```js
$("#listfilters").on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(e) {
        if(this.checked) {
            alert($(this).val());             
        }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="listfilters">
    <p>
    <label for="showall"><input type="checkbox" id="showall" name="showall" value="showall">&nbsp;
    Show All</label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="showfl"><input type="checkbox" id="showfl" name="showfl" value="Filtered">&nbsp;
    Filtered</label>
    </p>
</div>
```